why is output of a voltage follower non zero
Why is the output of a voltage follower non-zero and equal to the voltage at the non-inverting terminal if the voltages at both the inverting and non-inverting terminals are the same?

Because it's a follower and not a differential amplifier.

That is how feedback works.
Because op-amp can be thought as an ideal device where the output voltage does anything that is required to make the inverting and non-inverting voltages equal.
So when used as a follower, the output is connected to inverting input. Therefore the output must match non-inverting input to have equal voltage on inverting and non-inverting input.

In an op-amp configured with negative feedback, the voltage at the inverting input approximately tracks the voltage at the non-inverting input. The difference between the two is known as the error voltage. This error voltage is quite small because the open loop gain of an op-amp is quite large.
$$V_{error}=\frac{V_{out}}{A_{ol}}$$
For some purposes, the error voltage can be considered negligible. But, for understanding why the output of an op-amp is not zero, we must use the more precise understanding that the error voltage is generally not precisely 0.

And the offset voltage is often much larger than the error voltage.
